# db2 Type 4 driver downlaod

Tags: db2

I want to connect to the Db2 data base server with java application, I use type4 driver, can you please tell me exact location to download DB2 Type4 driver

Thanq in advance

Answer (score 0):

The actually recommended way is to get this from the DB2 server you are working with because it quarantees you get the correct version of them. You can find them from /sqllib/java .